# Python/PyGame - health bar is stuck; the -= operator does not appear to be working

Tags: python, pygame

I am unable to find the source of my error, the 'health' goes down once, but fails to update continuously. The failure seems to originate from line 105, where the '-=' operator does not appear to work...

```
import pygame, random, funks
class screen_attributes():
    def __init__(self):
        global screen
        self.WIDTH=screen.get_width()
        self.HEIGHT=screen.get_height()
        self.CAPTION='space_race'
pygame.init()
s_info = pygame.display.Info()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((s_info.current_w,s_info.current_h),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
main=screen_attributes()
pygame.display.set_caption(main.CAPTION)
def __init__():
    global main
    global exited
    exited = False
    global objects
    objects=[]
    for i in range(0, 50):
        objects.append(star())
    for i in range(0, 5):
        objects.append(battery())
    objects+=[ship()]
    for i in range(-1*(main.WIDTH-10),2*(main.WIDTH-10), 320):
        objects.append(asteroid(i,main.HEIGHT*-1))
        objects.append(asteroid(i,main.HEIGHT*2))
    for i in range(-1*(main.HEIGHT-10),2*(main.HEIGHT-10), 256):
        objects.append(asteroid(main.WIDTH*-1,i))
        objects.append(asteroid(main.WIDTH*2,i))
    global ui
    ui=[health_bar()]
    global flow
    flow='up'

class ship():
    def __init__(self):
        global main
        self.x= main.WIDTH/2-75
        self.y= main.HEIGHT/2-200
        self.direction= 'up'
        self.directions={'up':0 , 'down':180 , 'right':270 , 'left':90 ,}
        self.original_image=pygame.image.load('ship.png')
        self.image=self.original_image
        self.rects=self.image.get_rect()
        self.type='ship'
    def update(self):
        global flow
        global ui
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:
            flow='up'
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
            flow='down'
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            flow='right'
        if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            flow='left'
        self.image=pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, self.directions[flow])
        for item in objects:
            if funks.collided(self, item):
                if item.type=='battery':
                    ui[0].health=1.00
class star():
    def __init__(self):
        global main
        self.image=pygame.image.load('star.png')
        self.x=random.randint(-1*(main.WIDTH-10),2*(main.WIDTH-10))
        self.y=random.randint(-1*(main.HEIGHT-10),2*(main.HEIGHT-10))
        self.type='star'
    def update(self):
        if flow=='up':
            self.y+=1
        if flow=='down':
            self.y-=1
        if flow=='right':
            self.x-=1
        if flow=='left':
            self.x+=1
class asteroid():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.image=pygame.image.load('asteroid.png')
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.rects=self.image.get_rect()
        self.type='asteroid'
    def update(self):
        if flow=='up':
            self.y+=1
        if flow=='down':
            self.y-=1
        if flow=='right':
            self.x-=1
        if flow=='left':
            self.x+=1
class health_bar():
    def __init__(self):
        global main
        self.health=1.00
        self.image=pygame.image.load('health.png')
        self.y=20
        self.x=main.WIDTH*0.8
        self.height=20
        self.width=200
    def update(self):
        if self.health > 0.00:
            self.health-=0.0001
            print self.health
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*self.health), self.height))
class battery():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x=random.randint(-1*(main.WIDTH-10),2*(main.WIDTH-10))
        self.y=random.randint(-1*(main.HEIGHT-10),2*(main.HEIGHT-10))
        self.image=pygame.image.load('battery.png')
        self.rects=self.image.get_rect()
        self.type='battery'
    def update(self):
        if flow=='up':
            self.y+=1
        if flow=='down':
            self.y-=1
        if flow=='right':
            self.x-=1
        if flow=='left':
            self.x+=1












__init__()
while not exited:
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        pygame.quit()
    pygame.event.get()
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    for item in objects:
        item.update()
        screen.blit(item.image, [item.x, item.y])
    for item in ui:
        item.update()
        screen.blit(item.image, [item.x, item.y])
    pygame.display.update()
```

The 'funks.py' file that is imported simply detects for collisions.

```
def collided(ob1, ob2):
    try:
        if ob1.x <= (ob2.x + (ob2.rect[0])) and (ob1.x + (ob1.rect[0])) >= ob2.x:
             if ob1.y <= (ob2.y + (ob2.rect[1])) and (ob1.y + (ob1.rect[1])) >= ob2.y:
                return True
    except:
        return 'no rects'
```

*Revision*
The flaw originates from the update function of the listed class:

```
class health_bar():
    def __init__(self):
        global main
        self.health=1.00
        self.image=pygame.image.load('health.png')
        self.y=20
        self.x=main.WIDTH*0.8
        self.height=20
        self.width=200
    def update(self):
        if self.health > 0.00:
            self.health-=0.0001
            print self.health
        self.image=pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (int(self.width*self.health), self.height))
```

Comment: Can you post a **minimal**, complete example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- questions should include the smallest possible code snippet which will reproduce the same problem. (Often, the process of isolating such a snippet will result in finding the problem without needing to ask a question).

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler you should post that as the answer as Im pretty sure you have exactly nailed OP's problem

Comment: @JoranBeasley except my math is terrible. It won't be 10,000 updates, it only needs 500 updates to change again - at 30fps that would be ~16 seconds, not 5 minutes. Still might be the issue - how long are you waiting for changes, @ChrisReal? How often is update being called?

Comment: at this point, there is no actual intended time, simply aiming for functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem myself. Thank you to those who gave productive answers, however i would like to inform all that the error originated from a portion of the code that did not seem entirely relevant or 'minimal'. In the 'spaceship' update function it checks to see if the ship is colliding with any 'batteries'. This bit of code is always returning True henceforth always changing the health back to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=5
x-=1
print x
```

works fine ...

```
class health_bar():
    def __init__(self):
        #global main
        self.health=1.00
        #self.image=pygame.image.load('health.png')
        self.y=20
        self.x=20
        self.height=20
        self.width=200
    def update(self):
        if self.health > 0.00:
            self.health-=0.0001
            print self.health

a = health_bar()
a.update()
a.update() 
a.update()
```

Comment: Exactly, which is why I am confused.

Comment: you might try printing the `id(self)` my guess is that you are reinstanciating the health_bar or something

Comment: or its a logic issue ... see @TessellatingHeckler 's comment on your original question